# c# regex split or replace. here's my code i did

Tags: regex, replace

I am trying to replace a certain group to "" by using regex.

I was searching and doing my best, but it's over my head.

What I want to do is,

```
string text = "(12je)apple(/)(jj92)banana(/)cat";
string resultIwant = {apple, banana, cat};
```

In the first square bracket, there must be 4 character including numbers.
and '(/)' will come to close.

Here's my code. (I was using matches function)

```
string text= @"(12dj)apple(/)(88j1)banana(/)cat";
string pattern = @"\(.{4}\)(?<value>.+?)\(/\)";

Regex rex = new Regex(pattern);
MatchCollection mc = rex.Matches(text);
if(mc.Count > 0)
{
  foreach(Match str in mc)
  {
    print(str.Groups["value"].Value.ToString());
  }
}
```

However, the result was 
apple
banana

So I think I should use replace or something else instead of Matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below regex would capture the word characters which are just after to `)`,

```
(?<=\))(\w+)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/eN2hY4/9)

Your c# code would be,

```
{
  string str = "(12je)apple(/)(jj92)banana(/)cat";
  Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(?<=\))(\w+)");
  foreach (Match m in rgx.Matches(str))
  Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/hXDtxc)

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=\))` Positive lookbehind is used here. It sets the matching marker just after to the `)` symbol.
- `()` capturing groups.
- `\w+` Then it captures all the following word characters. It won't capture the following `(` symbol because it isn't a word character.

Comment: I want to limit only 4 characters in the first square bracket, and only one character in the second square bracket.
I tried (.{4}<=\)) didn't work :P
I will be trying to achieve it!

Comment: so how the final result will look like?

Comment: I am trying it. Regex expression is totally complicated.

Comment: yes, you want like that. What's your expected result?

Comment: I'll show you an example.
text = "abcde(1111)fghij0(/)(/)jfidj(8829)jj(/)...
So, I want to remove all pairs. (4 characters)(/) is one pair.
from the example, the result i want is abcdefghij0(/)jfidjjj.

Comment: I think I confuse you. 
(4 characters)(/) <= one pair. 
abc(12ab)d(/)e(12)f(ajde)gh(/) => abcd(/)e(12)fgh.
I hope you understand what i am explaining :(